# Which (country)

Tags: questions, interrogatives

Can the word "country" be omitted in the following?

> 1. John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year. Which (**country**) did he like best?
> 2. John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year. In  which (**country**) did he meet Sarah?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Yes, you can omit *country*. It is understood that you’re asking about countries (the one he liked best).

2 - I was hesitant to say you could omit *country* in the second sentence at first, but I think it is grammatical. Something about it sounds a little stilted to me, though. "In which *one*...", "In which *of those*...", etc. are also correct, but that doesn't mean the original sentence is incorrect.

Comment: OP's example #2 isn't necessarily eliding/omitting the specific word ***country***, since it hasn't actually been used earlier. The format is perfectly valid even if we suppose it's a shorter version of *In which **of those** did he meet Sarah?* Where again, there's no real reason to suppose that's specifically a shorter version of *which of those **countries*** (the speaker might be thinking *which of those **places***, but it's effectively irrelevant which word he has in mind, ***if any***).

Comment: Oh wow... yeah, that's a good point. "Countries" is not used in the first sentence at all; the countries are just listed. Editing my answer.

Comment: I still think you're mistaken in asserting that *any* explicit noun must (or even "should") occur after ***which*** in such contexts. *We've got red wine and white wine. **Which** do you want?* Few people would ever bother to include a noun *(**colour, one, wine,** [of] **those**)* there.

Comment: I have changed my mind - I agree with you that an explicit noun is not needed. I still think that "In which" (by itself) sounds a bit too formal for normal speech (if this is meant to be speech). Maybe "in which" in general just sounds formal since putting the preposition at the beginning sounds like a conscious effort to be "correct". Written English of course has different conventions.

Comment: What's up with all that crossed out text??

Comment: @Lambie just made too many edits. Edited again, no crossed-out text now.

Answer (score 1):

John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year. Which (country) did he like best?

John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year. In which (country) did he meet Sarah?

The most natural, in regular conversation, would be:

**Where did he meet Sarah?** or: **Which country did he meet Sarah in?**

In which country did he meet Sarah? is grammatically correct and awkward in terms of usage unless the context is very formal.

Since the context of countries is established, there is no need to repeat it but you can if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

OP is mistaken even in supposing that the word ***country*** is "omitted" in the examples. That specific word never occurred earlier in the "conversation", and the second sentence could just as well have been *Which **place** did he like best?, In which **of those** did he meet her?* anyway.

But actually, there's no *syntactic* reason to identify *any* specific noun after ***which*** in such contexts. For example,...

> *We have red wine and white wine. **Which** do you prefer?*

...is a perfectly natural construction, in both formal *and* informal contexts (informally, ***We've got...*** Which do you **want**? would be more common, but that's irrelevant to the point under consideration).

---

It might help to note that ***which*** is sometimes identified as an *interrogative **pronoun***. That's to say, it's already a "nouny" sort of word anyway, so there's no reason to suppose ***grammar / syntax*** would require it always to be coupled to another noun. Of course, ***semantically*** it might be needed to clarify meaning / resolve ambiguity, but that clearly isn't the case with OP's examples.

Comment: Does "John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year. In which did he meet Sarah? / Which did he meet Sarah in?" sound OK? I suspect "bare which" with a preposition sounds bad when the antecedents are proper nouns.

Comment: I don't think the reason it's not so good in this specific context reflects any general principle that *"bare which" **without*** (typo?) *a preposition sounds bad when the antecedents are proper nouns*. It's just that the required context happens to require a "container" metaphor, that would normally be covered by ***where***, but simultaneously it needs to reflect the sense of "one item selected from a preceding list". Which can only really be done by including the preposition ***in** which*.

Comment: Compare "John received the box, in which he found 10 coins" with "John visited Ruritania, in which he met Sarah." The former with its common noun antecedent sounds better than the latter.

Comment: Consider also "John visited Ruritania, which he found to be a beautiful country." The sentence without a pre-which preposition, sounds better than "John visited Ruritania, in which he met Sarah."

Comment: But your *Ruritania, **in** which* example doesn't include the "one item selected from a preceding list" context, so there's no reason not to use ***where***. If we do have such a list, (*and* if we rephrase to a statement rather than a question as per OP's original), we end up with something like *John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year, **in the last of** which he met Sarah*. Stylistically awful, I know - but at least that would be *syntactically* "credible".

Comment: Right. Let's consider  "John has red, yellow, and green envelopes. Which  did he find a letter in?" vs. "John visited France, Spain, and Italy last year. Which did he meet Sarah in?"

Comment: Are they of equal acceptability?

Comment: Equal to *what?* Each other, or as alternatives to ***In** which did he find a letter / meet Sarah*? There are still plenty of people who'd say your versions are "suspect" because ending sentences with prepositions is something they don't approve of. But you can make your own mind up. (Or make up your own mind! :)

Comment: I am asking whether the second example is as acceptable as the first.

Comment: Just ignore the issue of preposition stranding.